# How do I read each character for each "line" in a list (in order) C#

Tags: c#

I am currently working on some code but I am stuck. I have a text file which contains names and each name is on a new line. I have read these names into a list but I would like to be able to read each letter of each line(Name in the text file) in order. If anyone could help me up I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have any reference code that you've tried? This is generally helpful to diagnose a specific problem you may have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will load the file c:\temp\test-1.txt into a StreamReader, read each line until it hits EOF, and print each character on a new line to the console.  Modify as needed.

Note that if your file is stored on one really long line (and is a really big file) you'll have to do some additional handling here to avoid out of memory exceptions.

```
string line;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\temp\\test-1.txt"))
{
    while (reader.Peek() > -1)
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();
        foreach (char c in line)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They may want to throw a Text.Split() if he wants to separate the fname/lname/suffix, etc on space or comma.. Did something similar with the US census data for a project...

Comment: Sure, but the actual request was just reading each character lin a line from a file

Answer (score 2):

Here is a program that will read a file using [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

names.txt:

```
Bob
Mary
Sue
```

Code:

```
var file = @"C:\temp\names.txt";

Console.WriteLine("Opening file {0}", file);
foreach(var name in File.ReadLines(file))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Printing letters in name: {0}", name);
    foreach(var letter in name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(letter);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Done reading file");
```

Output:

```
Opening file C:\temp\names.txt
Printing letters in name: Bob
B
o
b
Printing letters in name: Mary
M
a
r
y
Printing letters in name: Sue
S
u
e
Done reading file
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use Linq to get all chars from a file:

```
var allChars = File.ReadLines(filename).SelectMany(c => c);
```

Which you can then iterate like this:

```
foreach (char ch in allChars)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ch);
}
```